# Can't find FileHiddenName from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am using an iframe to upload an image. So I have two files - the file for the iframe and the file that will display the image. When the link to display the iframe is clicked this code is run:

```
function ShowUploadImageOut(RecordID) {
    $('#<%=hfPieceID.ClientID %>').val(RecordID);
    $("#dvAddImageOutturn").html(
        '<iframe id="iframeUpload" src="utilities/UploadPOD.aspx?id=uploadOutturn"></iframe>'
    );
}
```

On the iframe is an upload button that saves the image to a folder on the computer and sets the image file name to `FileNameHidden`

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fuUpload.HasFile)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["id"] == "uploadOutturn")
        {
            String Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PieceOutturnFolder"].ToString()
                + Company.Current.CompCode;
            string FileName = fuUpload.FileName;

            if (File.Exists(Path + "/" + FileName))
            {
                File.Delete(Path + "/" + FileName);
            }

            fuUpload.SaveAs(Path + "/" + FileName);
            filename = FileName;
            imgTemp.ImageUrl = "/thumbnail.ashx?ImgFilePath=" + Path.Replace("/", "\\")
                + "\\" + FileName + @"&width=200&height=400";
            FileNameHidden.Value = FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

`FileNameHidden` has the property `clientidmode` set to `"static"`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="FileNameHidden" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
```

Back on the page for displaying the image there is a save button. This button takes the value from `FileNameHidden` and sets it to a hidden field. This new hidden field is used to save the file name to the database:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfUploadedPieceHubImageFile" runat="server" />

<div id="dvAddEditImageOutturn" class="dvdraggable">   
    <div id="dvAddImageOutturn"></div>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPieceHubUpdateImage"
        onclick="btnUpdatePieceImage_Click"
        OnClientClick="CloseUploadWindow();return GetPieceOutturnFilename();"
        CssClass="btnSaveSmall"
        runat="server"
    ></asp:LinkButton>
</div>

function GetPieceOutturnFilename() {
    if ($('#iframeUpload').contents().find('#FileNameHidden').length > 0) {
        $("#<%= hfUploadedPieceHubImageFile.ClientID %>").val(
            $('#iframeUpload').contents().find('#FileNameHidden').val()
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is in the `GetPieceOutturnfile` function. `$('#iframeUpload').contents().find('#FileNameHidden').length` is always zero. It should be finding the `FileNameHidden` from the iframe.

Going through the code I can see `FileNameHidden` definitely gets set the name of the image:

```
<input name="FileNameHidden" type="hidden" id="FileNameHidden" value="test.jpg">
```

So I don't understand why it says the length is zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with the `btnPieceHubUpdateImage` for the `onClientClick`:

```
OnClientClick="CloseUploadWindow();
return GetPieceOutturnFilename();"
```

It was closing the window first then trying to save the `FileNameHidden` from the Iframe. Swapping these around so it calls `GetPieceOutturnFileName` first solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working with this code. Make sure the content loaded into the iframe (child.html) is on the same domain or it will not work for security reasons. Also, it will not work running the files on your desktop. They need to be served from a server.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#iframeUpload").load(function() {
        var fileName = $(this).contents().find("#FileNameHidden").val();
        console.log(fileName);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="iframeUpload" src="child.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="FileNameHidden" type="hidden" id="FileNameHidden" style="display:none" value="test.jpg">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If this does not help solve your issue, you should provide files or a jsfiddle.

Comment: ok I tried editing the GetPieceOutturnFileName function to your code but it doesn't go into the ` $("#iframeUpload").load(function () {` so does that mean its not findiing the iframe? I added the change I made to the function to my question

Comment: The load function was a requirement of my basic example. Without load the fileName would return null because the iframe contents would still be loading when ready was called. It is hard for me to tell how your application works by looking at the random code snippets in your question. If you could provide a link to a basic version of your application it would make it a lot easier for people to diagnose your issue.

Comment: @user123456789 I took a look at the files. There is a lot in there and I was unable to run it due to not having the required dependancies. I would recommend simplifying your scenario by building a basic html version of the page you are having an issue with. Only keep the functionality that you are trying to debug. Similar to my answer above. If you can get the problem to occur in a working jsfiddle, people will probably figure out the issue right away.